# Run Microsoft Visual Studio C# project in Linux

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ubuntu, .net-core, bitcoin

I downloaded a c# .net project from git onto ubuntu and installed .net libraries from http://www.mono-project.com/download/#download-lin and also **donet core** from https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#linuxubuntu.

when I run `donet restore`, I am getting the following error

> /home/ubuntu/DotNetWallet/src/DotNetWallet/DotNetWallet.xproj(8,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/1.0.3/Microsoft/VisualStudio/v14.0/DotNet/Microsoft.DotNet.Props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

I guess the problem is with the `DotNetWallet.xproj` which generally is compatible with visual studio but how can I run it on ubuntu?

So, I 
used 'dotnet migrate' ,and then used 'donet restore', it now works fine, but when I run 'donet build', I am getting the following error

FakeData.cs(1,20): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'KeyManagement' does not exist in the namespace 'DotNetWallet' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [/home/ubuntu/DotNetWallet/src/DotNetWallet/DotNetWallet.csproj]

And, here is the git repo link https://github.com/nopara73/DotNetWallet

Comment: I would suggest to delete all project related files and/or reopen it in i.e. MonoDevelop - this will get rid of all VS specific settings from project.

Comment: run `dotnet migrate` first to convert project.json based format to sln/csproj. Then run `dotnet restore`. `*.xproj` file format is not supported by ms any more.

Comment: @Kalten, Thank you, it works but now I get another error when I run 'donet build' FakeData.cs(1,20): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'KeyManagement' does not exist in the namespace 'DotNetWallet' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [/home/ubuntu/DotNetWallet/src/DotNetWallet/DotNetWallet.csproj]

Comment: Contact the original developers to see what exactly you should do, or you will have to share the whole git repo for others to check what might fix the issue.

Comment: @Lex Li, I have included the git repo link in the question

Comment: It seems to be a broken repo by design. Give it up or ask its author for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many step are required in order to run this project.

First delete `global.json` file and then run `dotnet migrate` and remove the backup directory.

(Optional) In some case you will need to clean the solution. If `DotNetWallet.xproj` and `project.json` are still there, remove it and run the twxo following command.

- `dotnet sln remove src/DotNetWallet/DotNetWallet.xsproj`
- `dotnet sln add src/DotNetWallet/DotNetWallet.csproj`

Then, remove the first line  (`using DotNetWallet.KeyManagement;`) from `FakeData.cs` file. This is an unused using statment. there are no impact to remove it.

Now, you can run `dotnet restore`, `dotnet build` then `dotnet test`.

Comment: @Kalten.Thank you!!!It works, I had to use dotnet restore before using dotnet build

Comment: @pavikirthi, Thx. Edited.

Comment: DO NOTE: Microsoft documetation: ”This command is deprecated. The dotnet migrate command is no longer available starting with .NET Core 3.0 SDK. It can only migrate a Preview 2 .NET Core project to a 1.x .NET Core project, which is out of support.”